# How to ignore Get Table Text from Cell, if xpath of cell not match

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, robotframework

How to ignore Get Table Text from Cell, if xpath of cell not match? Becuase i want my test case still continues testing.

```
 ${tableFinal}    Set Variable   xpath=/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div/form/table[3]
 ${totalPayAmount}      Get Table Text from Cell     ${tableFinal}         1   2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using either `Run Keyword And Continue On Failure` or `Run Keyword And Ignore Error` can help with this. In the [documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20And%20Continue%20On%20Failure) the entire family of `Run Keyword ....` keywords.

The difference between the two is that one just returns the value, whereas the other also provides the status of the Keyword execution.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case
    ${CoF_Pass_1}    Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    KW Pass
    ${CoF_Fail}      Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    KW Fail
    ${CoF_Pass_2}    Run Keyword And Continue On Failure    KW Pass

    ${IE_Pass_1}    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    KW Pass
    ${IE_Fail}      Run Keyword And Ignore Error    KW Fail
    ${IE_Pass_2}    Run Keyword And Ignore Error    KW Pass 

*** Keywords ***
KW Pass
    [Return]    SomeRandomValue
KW Fail
    Fail    SomeFaileMessage
```

This then results into:

```
Starting test: Test Case
INFO : ${CoF_Pass_1} = SomeRandomValue
FAIL : SomeFaileMessage
INFO : ${CoF_Fail} = None
INFO : ${CoF_Pass_2} = SomeRandomValue
INFO : ${IE_Pass_1} = ('PASS', u'SomeRandomValue')
FAIL : SomeFaileMessage
INFO : ${IE_Fail} = ('FAIL', u'SomeFaileMessage')
INFO : ${IE_Pass_2} = ('PASS', u'SomeRandomValue')
Ending test: Test Case
```